# How to mine with 1k PC's?

Tags: mining-pools, network, mining-profitability, cpu-mining

I have a network of 1k+ PC's (not a botnet). Could you advice me how can I mine effectively for one pool, for only one pool account, maybe you have any solutions?

I think it should be CPU miner because I can't bypass GPU drivers on each pc.

All PC's in network have our application always running, so I think better way is to add to our application mining code, but I cant find any simply solution without useless features.

Comment: fyi Roman, you are being downvoted because the question of whether CPU mining is even profitable at all has been answered here extensively (it is extremely unprofitable).

Answer (score 2):

You will be using way more power(electricity) than you can ever gain in any virtual currency at the moment. To you the power might be free, but the owner(s) of the PC will pay dearly.